# JSF 2 Page not refreshing after action completes

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm having an issue where my page is not refreshing after an action completes.

I have this form on a page:

```
<h:form id="fundingResults">

    <p:ajaxStatus style="width:16px;height:16px;">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/loading4.gif" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="complete">
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>

    <p:dataTable>
        // some form elements in the table
    </p:dataTable>  

   <p:commandButton id="btnEdit" value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{fundingBacker.classifyProducts}" style="float: right;margin-top:15px;" />           

</h:form>
```

My classifyProducts method skeleton is like this:

```
public void classifyProducts() {
    // a bunch of stuff goes on in here
}
```

Shouldn't the page refresh automatically after the classifyProducts() method completes because of implicit naviation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primefaces command buttons send ajax requests by default. Try to add attribute `ajax='false'` to `p:commandButton`.

Comment: Awesome. I was not aware of this. It worked. I can't accept your answer for 8 more minutes though.

Comment: This isn't really a good idea. There's a reason the requests are ajax by default. Refreshing the entire page is usually not necessary.

Comment: I need to refresh the page because in my classifyProducts function, there's logic in there and based on the outcome of the logic, it either updates the page, or redirects to a different page.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify what parts of the page to refresh. For example adding update="@form" to the commandbutton tag should to the trick here, or you could specify the id of the individual components to update.

Comment: Not tree. An action attribute should do a redirect. an actionListener needs an update to actually update a section of the page. I was not aware that primefaces was ajax=true by default. At least that's my understanding of it. I could very well be wrong though..